# Activity restarts after showing the Ad from Admob

Tags: android, android-activity, admob

I have an app which has an activity-A. I am showing an Interestial Ad from Admob in it. This is achieved using the Google play services. When there is a weak signal, when I clicked the home button in middle of the app, I could see the home screen. Now when I again clicked the app, the app freshly starts (instead of continuing from the place where i left) and when I close the app using the close button which actually calls the finish() statement and closes the app. But after closing the app the app continuous the activity from the first place where i have pressed the home button which Is very strange to me. Kindly help me to resolve this

This is not happening when I have full internet signal / no signal.

Comment: What does the log look like. I suspect an Exception is being thrown which is crashing the app. By default Android will restart a crashed app.